# How to edit .gitignore in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gitignore

My `.gitignore` is not visible in Jupyter Lab Files tab. Is there any way to show hidden files there?

Comment: One workaround is to use the terminal and edit the file in a text editor like vim or nano

Comment: you can use alternative file explorer like https://github.com/ranger/ranger or sth similar

Comment: Another workaround - just edit the gitignore file in your github account online

Answer (score 23):

This is still an open issue in JupyterLab:

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2049

As a temporary workaround, you can start your jupyter lab via the below command (as mentioned in the above URL) to edit hidden files:

```
jupyter lab --ContentsManager.allow_hidden=True
```

Comment: Thanks works. For shortcut, can define an alias on linux, e.g., `alias jl='jupyter lab --no-browser --ContentsManager.allow_hidden=True'` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Is there a way to toggle this without having to relaunch jlab everytime?

Comment: Are you able to toggle this without restarting jlab?

Answer (score 9):

Actual big brain solution
`ln -s .gitignore gitignore`

The purpose of this command is to create a symbolic link named `gitignore` (not hidden) to the hidden file (`.gitignore`).  That way Jupyter (and Jupyter Lab) will show it to you and let you open it, but you're actually editing the underlying hidden file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Geinus (big brain) solution @Hassan-ismail-fawaz!

Answer (score 7):

JupyterLab currently **lacks the ability to toggle hidden files** in the browser.

You can simply **rename the file in a terminal session** to view/edit .gitignore as needed:

**1) Create gitignore as TEXT file**:

[image]

**2) Rename file to gitignore (no preceding dot) in JupyterLab**:

You can now view/edit in JupyterLab as needed.

**3) Prior to pushing to GitHub, add the preceding dot by running the following in terminal**:

```
mv gitignore .gitignore
```

Whenever you need to **view/edit** the file, change it back to visible:

```
mv .gitignore gitignore
```

...and edit the file using JupyterLab.

If you ever need to see the file listed, run the following in terminal:

```
ls -a
```

Comment: @Marcin I believe it doesn't support it. The other answer is just a workaround that requires you to restart the server. Jupyter lab is still missing a view menu toggle, like the one in all other programs.

Answer (score 5):

Now in AWS SageMaker Jupyter Lab, one can access .gitignore file by menu "Git -> Open .gitignore".
[image]

Comment: This seems specific to an Amazon product and not related to the original JupyterLab, which is what this question is about.