# Installing nodejs dependencies manually

Tags: node.js, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I need to install nodejs (to use extensions on jupyterlab) at work and have to get each package manually imported into the organisation before I can install it, so from conda-forge I've imported nodejs and what I thought were all of the dependency libraries but I still get the below error when installing nodejs

```
Fetching package metadata .....
Solving package specifications: 
PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:
            
  - nodejs -> __glibc >=2.17,<3.0.a0
  - nodejs -> icu >=68.1,<69.0a0 -> libgcc-ng >=7.5.0 -> _libgcc_mutex 0.1 conda_forge
  - nodejs -> icu >=68.1,<69.0a0 -> libgcc-ng >=7.5.0 -> _openmp_mutex >=4.5
  - nodejs -> libuv >=1.41.0,<1.42.0a0
  - nodejs -> openssl >=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a -> ca-certificates
  - nodejs -> zlib >=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0
We have searched for the packages in the following channels:
```

These are the packages I've manually imported:

[image]

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong or if there's an easier way to get to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which extensions are you trying to install?

Comment: I can install the extension but all of them need nodejs 10.0.0+ to run

Comment: In this case I want to use the git extension

Comment: For JupyterLab 3.0 Node.js is not longer needed (and even not recommended by some extension authors, e.g. me).

Comment: Instead you should just install it with pip or conda, depending on which you use for package management, e.g. `pip install --upgrade jupyterlab jupyterlab-git` or `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab jupyterlab-git` see https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git#install

Comment: So I just did that and got the below error, also when installing the debugger extension it asked for nodejs>=12.0....

Comment: Failed to load the jupyterlab-git server extension
Git server extension is unavailable. Please ensure you have installed the JupyterLab Git server extension by running: pip install --upgrade jupyterlab-git. To confirm that the server extension is installed, run: jupyter server extension list.

Comment: I also ran the second recommended command and got 
xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx:~$ jupyter server extension list
Config dir: /home/xxxx/.jupyter
Config dir: /usr/etc/jupyter
Config dir: /usr/local/etc/jupyter

Comment: You should NOT install debugger extension for JupyterLab 3.0+ -> It is already pre-installed (ships as a core extension).

Comment: I replaced sensitive info with xxxxx- By the way, thanks for replying. This has been doing my heading, all I want to do is be able to use the git extension

Comment: okay, I was just testing installing another extension the only one I actually need is git

Comment: Are you using pyenv?

Comment: Wait the debugger relies on the xeus kernel, is that the same for the git extension?

Comment: No, git extension does not need any kernel.

Comment: Don't know what else I can do then... not using pyenv we have a cloudera setup if that helps

Comment: Could you please open an issue here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git/issues/new?assignees=&labels=type%3ABug&template=bug_report.md&title= providing your `pip list` or `conda list` there describing which command you used to install jupyterlab-git and tagging me in please?

Comment: Cheers I'll do that on my own comp a bit later, appreciate the help!

Comment: Couldn't see how to assign you but I've tagged in the content of the issue, let me know if you can't see it. Thanks again

Comment: Quick question - is there a way to view hidden files in jlab? would be great to be able to edit my .gitignore .bashrc without using vim

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57935922/6646912

Comment: Thanks I tried this on a old jlab version and didn't work but now does! Still wish there was a toggle

Comment: Waiting for the file tree view extension to be upgraded so it doesn't need nodejs now

Comment: Started using the xeus kernel and I don't seem to be getting any of the LSP integration features i.e. docstrings and param suggestion. There's no error on the juypterlab log either.  Any advice? I have searched a fair bit about this today but can't find any info

Comment: Sorry for bugging but I noticed you've build LSP 

Comment: You should get one of those links on your github where people can buy you a coffee from, I deffo owe you one by now

Comment: Tried installing lsp separately when I do jupyter server extension enable --user --py jupyterlab-lsp it says it can't be found but I can see the options in advanced settings

Comment: Try with underscore: jupyterlab_lsp

Comment: Also the server extension is actually `jupyter_lsp`. The frontend extension is `jupyterlab_lsp`. Depending on what you do you should either use `_` or `-`.

Comment: In general for quick questions we use: https://gitter.im/jupyterlab/jupyterlab